# Create activity in two feed groups in Stream Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getstream-io

I am using [Stream Rails](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails) to build an app with a feed. The `user` has some `page` which other users can follow. For that I created a `page` feed group. Here is my `Post` model -

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_one :post_item, inverse_of: :post

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_item
  include StreamRails::Activity
  as_activity


  def activity_object
    self.post_item
  end

  def activity_actor
    self.author
  end
end
```

However, the posts go to user's feed. How can I also make it go to the `page` feed group? I looked through the github code, and I think I have to override `activity_owner_feed`? But I also want the author to have a list of all the posts they have created. So the posts need to be in the `user` feed too.

Here is the corresponding code from my controller -

```
    # this method creates the post
    # This puts the post in user feed
    # I also want to add the post to page feed
    def create
        @post = current_user.posts.build post_params
        @post.save

        render json: { success: true }
      end

      # show all posts of a user

      def show
        feed = StreamRails.feed_manager.get_user_feed(current_user.id)
        enricher = StreamRails::Enrich.new
        results = feed.get()['results']
        @activities = enricher.enrich_activities(results)

        render json: { activity: @activities }
      end
```

Corresponding routes -

```
 post 'post/create'
 post 'post/show'
```

Comment: Would you add the corresponding code from the controller, view and route?

Comment: @ajm I have edited my question (no view because it's an API)

Comment: Can you give an example of what `feed = StreamRails.feed_manager.get_user_feed(current_user.id)` returns?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `activity_notify` and return an array of feeds to be notified.
It translates to [`to` target in the generated activity](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails/blob/301822076a939df7dca691e43cf794b81c62df14/lib/stream_rails/activity.rb#L97).